# Rails model best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an online ordering app. Here is the structure that I have:

Order has many items_variations, item_variations belongs to item. Order belongs to customer. Item has a price(column).

Now in the Order model I have a query to find the order amount, and individual amount like so

```
def self.order_amount
  Order.joins(:items).where(customer_id: customer_id).sum('items.price')
end

def amount_item
  ItemVariation.joins(:items).where(order_id: self.id).sum('items.price')
end
```

Is this the correct way to make this model? AFAIK, I should not be using ItemVariation in order.rb, but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: Does `ItemVariation` also belong_to `Order`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `has_many: through`

In Order.rb:

```
has_many :items, through: :item_variations

def amount_item
    items.sum(:price)
end
```

Comment: Is there a way I can improve order_amount

Comment: Probably, but it's hard to tell without seeing your models. What is the difference between `order_amount` and `amount_item`? Ideally an order belongs to a customer, so `order_amount` should just be `items.sum(:price)`

Comment: Actually in this case, we have an option of two(more in the future) users combining their orders, hence each order has 2 customers(for now).

Comment: Post, as code, the relationships between `Order`, `ItemVariation`, `Item` and `Customer`